# GWT Application Error - unable to add GWT class outside client package

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee

I need a help, I am designing a application using GWT as a front end. So I am writing a wrapper class as application main window, the condition is if I create this class inside the client package, it works fine but If I create the file outside client package it is not loading. The exception I am getting is :

```
[ERROR] [questwebtoolweb] - Line 27: No source code is available for type com.ibm.projects.qwt.client.ui.ApplicationDefaultWindow; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

if you need I can show you the code of my application. But that code is working fine if I put the stuff in client module.

I would really appriciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GWT it is important to follow the special package structure conventions.

Each GWT module can have a `client` subpackage for client side code, a `server` package for server side code like RPC servlets and a subfolder `public` for static files like CSS files or images.

Read the GWT documentation article [Organize Projects](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html) for details and how to redefine these package names.

So the essence is, if your class is not under the client package, the GWT compiler doesn't compile it to JavaScript for client side code.

Comment: first of all Thank you vanje .. but I am writing this class in the sub package of client package which google codline says that you can write the client code in the sub package of the client. Guidline : Within the client and server packages, you are free to organize your code into any subpackages you require.

Comment: Yes a subpackage of a module client package is also ok. You have to ensure that the client package is inside a GWT module (the package where your module GWT XML file is located) and that your module is inherited by your main module. Can you show us  your package structure with your GWT module XML files?